# JS validation, why this code won´t work?

Tags: javascript, validation

I can´t get the validation in JS, and don´t understand why it doesn´t work.
**The user should get an alert if at least one of the checkboxes isn´t checked**.
It doesn´t work, because the form gets submitted ok even if if none checkboxes are checked.

```
<body>
<script>
function validar()
{
var s1=document.getElementById('s1');
var s2=document.getElementById('s2');

if (s1.value==''||s2.value=='')
  {
  alert("You must check at least one!");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>

<form name="calcular" onsubmit="return validar()" method="post">
<input type ="checkbox" name="servicios[]" id="s1" value="sinservicios">Sin servicios<br>
<input type ="checkbox" name="servicios[]" id="s2" value="dosservicios">Dos servicios<br>

...
```

Comment: Define `doesn't work`.

Comment: Sorry about that (but didn´t need a -1 vote I guess). I´ve edited the question: It doesn´t work, because the form gets submitted ok if none checkboxes are checkes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try using the `checked` property to ensure that at least one of the 2 checkboxes is checked:

```
<script>
    function validar() {
        var s1 = document.getElementById('s1');
        var s2 = document.getElementById('s2');

        if (!s1.checked && !s2.checked) {
            alert('You must check at least one!');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Also notice we should return `true` in case the validation succeeds.

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you have used the `value` property. That's always gonna return the `value` attribute of your checkbox (`sinservicios` or `dosservicios`) no matter if the user checked or not this checkbox. It will never return an empty string which is what you seem to be testing for in your `if` condition.

Comment: A code example illustrating the correct approach doesn't need lots of explanation. A code example is always worth hundredth words (and comments like your of course).

Comment: Thanks, very useful! Using checked worked like a charm. But I think that my approach should have worked too.. I can´t see the error..

Comment: @RosamundaRosamunda In your example, the `value` of a checkbox will be the same regardless of whether the checkbox is checked or not. Checking the checkbox doesn't change the value.

Comment: The `value` of `s1` for example would always return "sinservicios". You don't want the value, you want the checked state.

Comment: @RosamundaRosamunda, there are 2 problems with your approach. The first problem is that your code is inconsistent. You return `false` if validation fails but where do you return `true`? Also, you are using the `value` property. Have you noticed the `value` attribute of your checkboxes? That's what you're gonna get, no matter if the checkbox has been checked or not. You'll never gonna get an empty string which is what you seem to be testing against. Also do you realize the difference between the `||` and `&&` operators in javascript? Even if `.value` was returning empty string your code ...

Comment: ... woudln't have worked because you are testing whether at least one of the 2 checkboxes is checked, whereas according to your requirements, both checkboxes must be checked for validation to pass.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I mean any of the checkboxes, I mean, at least one should be checked. I´m editing the question now!